# Config file in a csv (or txt) format

Tags: r

I want to create a config file. In an R file it would look like the following:

```
#file:config.R
min_birthday_year <- 1920
max_birthday <- Sys.Date() %m+% months(9)
min_startdate_year <- 2010
max_startdate_year <- 2022
```

And in the main script I would do: `source("config.R")` .

However, now  I want to source the config data from a .csv file. Does anyone have any idea how to? The file could also be in a .txt format

Comment: I'm wondering: why exactly? Wouldn't changing a csv file be as much as a hassle as changing a R file? Putting thinks in an alternative format might only make it harder to read.

Comment: I know, but tell that to my manager

Comment: ok, send me his e-mailaddress

Comment: sadistic@jackass.com

Comment: hey, that's my e-mailadress! ;) But seriously, how would you (or probably he) imaging the CSV or TXT to be formatted? Is he wants something different, he should come with a proper requirements description.

Comment: If you don't mind a package dependency then the `config` package might be a good bet: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/config/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would suggest is looking into the [config](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/config/vignettes/introduction.html) package.
It allows you to specify variables in a yaml text file. I haven't used it but it seems pretty neat and looks like it may be a good solution.

If you don't want to use that, then if your csv is something like this, with var names in one column and values in the next:

```
min_birthday_year,1920
max_birthday,Sys.Date() %m+% months(9)
min_startdate_year,2010
max_startdate_year,2022
```

then you could do something like this:

```
# Read in the file
# assuming that names are in one column and values in another
# will create vars using vals from second col with names from first

config <- read.table("config.csv", sep = ",")

# mapply with assign, with var names in one vector and values in the other
# eval(parse()) call to evaluate value as an expression - needed to evaluate the Sys.Date() thing. 
# tryCatch in case you add a string value to the csv at some point, which will throw an error in the `eval` call

mapply(
  function(x, y) {
    z <- tryCatch(
      eval(parse(text = y)),
      error = function(e) y
    )
    assign(x, z, inherits = TRUE)
  },
  config[[1]],
  config[[2]]
)
```